# How do I use vscode-pets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to programming and saw the [VS Code Pets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tonybaloney.vscode-pets) in an article, and thought it could be a cool little thing to add to my environment, but I cant seem to figure out how to run it. The description of it just says to run `vscode-pets.start`, but where exactly do I run that command?

Comment: We finally got rid of Clippy, now we get it back in VSC see [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tonybaloney.vscode-pets)

Answer (score 5):

To launch the extension you can open the Command Palette (`View > Command Palette`) and type "Pet", and you'll see options such as `Pet Coding: Start pet coding session` to launch a pet window; `Pet Coding: Spawn additional pet`, in which a menu will pop up with various animals that you can add; or `Pet Coding: Throw ball` to play catch with the pets; etc.

You can also customize the extension, such as changing the default color (brown) and animal (cat), the default size (nano) and location (window), background scenery (none), et cetera by going to `File > Preferences > Settings` and typing in "Pet", in which case you should see various results including `vscode-pets (5)`. Click on that and you can then access drop-down menus to change the defaults, such as moving it to the Explorer area (which is smaller and and which has handy little plus and circle buttons to quickly spawn more pets (+) or throw a ball (o).

Answer (score 4):

Open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> and enter it there.

Answer (score 3):

To begin with, you will have to make sure that you have correctly installed the extension. The simplest way to do this is to directly install the extension within the Visual Studio Code extension tab. From the extensions tab search bar, simply enter `'vscode-pets'`, and click on the extension authored by *Anthony Shaw*:

[image: Where to find search and correct extension]

Finally, click the `install` button either in the extensions search tab, or in the extension description page that should have opened after clicking on the extension in the search tab. You will know that the extension is installed when you are given the options to disable/uninstall the extension, as shown here:

[image: Image showing you have installed extension]

From here (upon installation), we can 'run' the extension in a couple different ways. To begin with, you can open the Command Palette to start a 'pet coding session'. This is what will allow you to launch a window within VS Code for pets to move around in. To bring up the Command Palette, you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+P` (for Windows/Linux) or `Cmd(⌘)+Shift+P` (for MacOS). Alternatively, you can navigate to the VS Code header, and click `View > Command Palette` to bring it up. Doing any of these should bring up the command palette, as shown here:

[image: Image showing command palette]

Now, in order to interact with the extension from the command palette, you will have to start any commands with the phrase `Pet Coding:`. After entering this into the command palette, some specific commands will be displayed to you, but you can begin to enter any possible commands for them to be displayed and eventually executed. To begin with, you should execute the command `Pet Coding: Start pet coding session`, which may already be displayed upon opening the command palette:

[image: Starting pet coding session in the command palette]

Upon running this command, a pet window should open. Depending on the settings for your vscode-pets extension, this will either be in the `explorer` tab (the default option), as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVIQ6.png), or it will be in its own dedicated panel, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CfXE.png). If you would like to change the location of the pet window, then from the VS Code header, navigate to `File > Preferences > Settings`, and then in the search bar, type `vscode-pets`. You should see these settings:

[image: VS Code settings screen]

From here, you can modify multiple settings, including pet attributes and the theme. But in particular, you are able to change between the explorer/panel options from the `Vscode-pets: Position` drop down menu. This will alter where the pet panel is located upon starting a new pet coding session.

This is essentially all that has to be done to get a pet coding session up and running properly. Then, it is just a case of bringing up the command palette (as explained earlier) to interact with pets. To get started, you can run the command `>Pet Coding: Spawn additional pet` to spawn your first pet. Simply select further options for your pet (such as type of animal, colour, name etc.) from the command palette prompts that will appear. Furthermore, if you have a VS Code Pets session in your explorer tab, then you can spawn pets, throw a ball or delete a pet using the buttons located within the tab.

Answer (score 1):

pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` and next command
[image]

in case you added many pets and can't find how to remove them

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command after you install the extension. Open the command palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` on Windows/Linux or `Cmd(⌘)+Shift+P` on MacOS. The commands are preceded with `Pet Coding`.

The most up to date documentation can be found on the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/tonybaloney/vscode-pets#readme).

I have been working on updating the documentation for this extension. Please let me know if there are gaps or improvements that can be added.

Cheers!